# Git is saying this a directory both exists and yet it does not exist

Tags: git

[image]

Git is saying this a directory both exists and yet does not exist.

Comment: What do you see if you print the directory list?

Comment: The first line is Git. The second line is PowerShell. They might not be referring to the same path.

Comment: @matt yep.... sounds like a case-insensitive-fs problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since `~` might be interpreted differently, try a simple relative path:

```
git clone https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs .emacs.d
```

That will create the folder right where you are (`C:\Users\<YourLogin>`).